# How to remove selected date rectangle in QCalendarWidget and small icons in widgets

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5

I'm writing my own implementation of QCalendarWidget. I want dates to be selectable but I don't want to see default selection rectangle. It looks like that:
[image]

And my code:

```
in constructor: setSelectionMode(SingleSelection);

void ShiftCalendar::paintCell(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, const QDate &date) const
{
        if(date == selectedDate()) {
            fillCell(painter, rect, CalendarWidget::cellFillColor);
        }

        drawCellText(painter, rect, QString::number(date.day()), color);
}

void ShiftCalendar::fillCell(QPainter *painter, const QRect &rect, const QColor &color) const
{
    painter->save();

    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    painter->setPen(QPen(color));
    painter->setBrush(QBrush(color));
    painter->drawEllipse(fRect.center(), rect.width() / 2, rect.height() / 2);

    painter->restore();
}
```

What can I do?

The second problem as can be seen in the picture is the small size of pushbuttons icons and comboboxes icons. It looks fine on desktop but on Android it's small all the time. Modifying icon size doesn't have any effect.

EDIT:

First problem solved with adding `selection-background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);` to widget's stylesheet. Second one still not solved.

Comment: what's the type of the icons? what's the real size of the icons?

Comment: These are PNGs 128x128

Comment: I know dump question but, have you somewhere specified a size? QML, ...??

Answer (score 2):

```
QAbstractItemView *view = findChild<QAbstractItemView*>();

if(view) {

    view->setItemDelegate(//inherit QItemDelegate and override paint event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have different DPI versions of your icons? This page discusses how large various icons should be:
http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html

Comment: It's problem with Qt, this link isn't helpful for me.